# boolean field in redshift copy

Tags: postgresql, amazon-redshift

I am producing a comma-separated file in S3 that needs to be copied to a staging table in a redshift database using the postgres `COPY` command.

It has one `boolean` field.  With every sensible way I can think of to represent the boolean value in the file, redshift copy complains, usually with "Unknown boolean format".

I'm going to give up and change the staging table field to a `smallint` so that I can proceed with the copy and translate the value on the load from staging to the final redshift table, but I'm curious if anyone knows the correct incantation.

Comment: Could you provide example data, the definition of the table, the COPY command, and any relevant rows from `stl_load_errors`?

Comment: The AWS Documentation still appears to be silent on this. Thanks for posting the question here and "creating the missing documentation".

Answer (score 1):

A zero or one works just fine for us.

Check your loads carefully, it may well be another issue that's 'pushing' invalid data into your boolean column.

For instance, we had all kinds of crazy characters embedded in our data that would cause errors like that. I eventually settled on using the `US` character for the record separator.

Comment: In fact, zero and one was the first thing I tried.  I'll experiment on a copy of the old table layout, as I've now invoked the workaround of just making it a smallint field.  Thanks for letting me know my first instinct was likely right...

Answer (score 0):

Check to make sure you're excluding the headers during the `COPY` command.

I ran into the same problem, but adding the `ignoreheader 1` option (ignores 1 header line during import) solved the issue.